# How to add custom data into laravel queue jobs table or medify queue jobs payload for additional data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, queue, jobs, laravel-5.6

Laravel version 5.6

Laravel queues jobs are working fine, but I have additional requirements, please read below.

How can I add some additional values in jobs table such as job_source, job_type in queue jobs table?

Or at-least modify job payload to add some additional data.

Purpose of this is to keep records of all jobs which has been successfully executed along with additional data. I have a mysql trigger on jobs table on delete to keep all jobs records in a separate table named jobs_history, so I can keep track of all jobs which has been successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your own `Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue` implementation adding those fields you need. There is a protected function `buildDatabaseRecord` that looks like the function to update. Here is a related post about this topic https://medium.com/@assertchris/laravel-extending-queues-883bf32040b3