# Add fields to Laravel job records?

Tags: laravel, job-queue

I have a working Laravel 9 queued job class  using the 'database' driver.

I would like to show these jobs on a website and therefore I would like to add and save a value on a custom field  on these jobs records when they are constructed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907972/add-custom-field-to-laravel-queued-job-records https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387886/how-to-add-custom-data-into-laravel-queue-jobs-table-or-medify-queue-jobs-payloa - chances are you'll have to extend the database queue driver to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.